# What causes the mouthfeel from a French Press?

Tags: french-press, mouthfeel

The taste of a well-made French Press-brewed cup is made complete (in my opinion) by the velvety, full-bodied richness that can only be described as "mouthfeel". Which aspects of this brewing method cause that quality to be highlighted?

Answer (score 4):

More of the oils in the coffee remain as opposed to being filtered out. The coffee sits in the water, nothing is filtered out. The plunger leaves the oil in the coffee and prevents the grinds from going into the coffee cup (unless you used a very fine grind in which case the fine particles will go through the filter).

Comment: The plunger allows more fine sediment to seep into the cup.  Some of that body is caused by fine particulate matter that a paper filter would remove.

Comment: I think you make the leap that more oils/sediment = more mouthfeel, which might be true, but I'm not convinced by your answer as it stands. Maybe provide some outside resources to support your assertion?